# .properties file read by Java web app disappears

Tags: java, tomcat, properties-file

We've been facing a problem for some time now and I have no idea what's going on. I hope I'm missing something very obvious. Here's the situation:

We've got a bunch of Windows computers out there and each one of them is running an Apache Tomcat. The `webapps` folder of these Tomcats contains, among other things, a WAR file for a Java web app (`myApp.war`), the directory tree that corresponds to the deployment of that web app, and a simple folder (not a web app deployment) that contains a `.properties` file.

```
webapps
  |--myFolder
  |  `--myFile.properties
  |--myApp
  |  |--META-INF
  |  |--WEB-INF
  |  |--img
  |  ...
  |--myApp.war
  ...
```

The `myApp` application reads the file `myFile.properties` from time to time. It does not read it very often. When it does it should be a really quick operation: open file, read a couple properties, close. The code is clean and simple, the file stream should always get closed even in the face of exceptions.

The `myApp` application is sometimes hot redeployed by overwriting the `myApp.war` file.

Finally, those computers aren't in a friendly environment: sometimes they suffer from power outages or they're just not shut down properly.

The problem we're facing is that, sometimes, the file `myFile.properties` either

- disappears, or
- disappears and a `tmp.properties` file with the same contents appears in its place, or
- its content is erased.

We don't know exactly when does this happen, as we usually find out later.

Anybody knows what could be causing that, and what should be done to prevent it?

Comment: If your application is reading the file from time to time, I assume it means it expects the file to change from time to time. What is the entity that changes it?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I'm pretty sure the file is only ever edited manually.

Comment: There must be another process editing that file.